# Center 3 asymmetric div by center of the second one

Tags: html, css, center

Sounds similar with other questions but my question like this: I want to join 2 different logos together with a plus icon between them. The logos must be at the same height but maintain the ratio. So most of the time some logo will be longer than the other. When I center it with `text-align`, the result is far different from what I want:

[image]

I want to align it center by the `+` mark.

Here is my code:

```css
div#coopLogo div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo-container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#middle-indicator {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <div id="coopLogo">
    <div>Brand 1 logo(longer)</div>
    <div>+</div>
    <div>B2 logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="middle-indicator"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vskuvw3s/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Now I solved it. I moved the logos into the "plus" `div` and align it center, then I change the `position` of the logos to `absolute`.
My updated HTML:

```css
div#coopLogo div {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

div#coopLogo {
  height: 50px;
}

.plus {
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lg-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

.lg-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}

#logo-container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#middle-indicator {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <div id="coopLogo">
    <div class='plus'>
      <img class='lg-left' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3efOW.png">+
      <img class='lg-right' src="https://assets.crossref.org/logo/crossref-logo-landscape-200.svg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="middle-indicator"></div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vskuvw3s/20/
If you guys have other ways to do that or any advice to improve, please feel free to comment/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positioning unless you want element overlapping.

Options to achieve desired layout.

Update: To use with images move them to `div`s instead of text and `max-width: 100%`;`or add needed height for container (`#coopLogo`).

#### Flexbox

You can use nested flexbox to achieve desired layout. Demo:

```css
#coopLogo {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its children will be flex items */
  display: flex;
}

/* just adding non-breakable space */
#coopLogo > *:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "\A0";
}

#coopLogo > :first-child {
  /* move flex-items (children) to the right */
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#coopLogo > :first-child {
  /* move flex-items (children) to the left */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#coopLogo > :first-child,
#coopLogo > :last-child {
  /* occupy remaining width */
  flex: 1 0 0;
  /* become a flex-container */
  display: flex;
}

#middle-indicator {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <div id="coopLogo">
    <div>Brand 1 logo(longer)</div>
    <div>+</div>
    <div>B2 logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="middle-indicator"></div>
```

#### Tables

You can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for children to achieve desired layout. This was has the best browser support.

```css
#coopLogo {
  display: table;
}

#coopLogo > * {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* just adding non-breakable space */
#coopLogo > *:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "\A0";
}

#coopLogo > :first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

#coopLogo > :first-child,
#coopLogo > :last-child {
  width: 50%;
}

#middle-indicator {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <div id="coopLogo">
    <div>Brand 1 logo(longer)</div>
    <div>+</div>
    <div>B2 logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="middle-indicator"></div>
```

#### CSS Grid Layout

Using new CSS Grid module will solve this task

```css
#coopLogo {
  /* becoma a grid-container */
  /* its children will be grid-items */
  display: grid;
  /* specify column width of children */
  /* 1fr means remaining space */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

/* just adding non-breakable space */
#coopLogo > *:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "\A0";
}

#coopLogo > :first-child {
  /* move content to the right */
  margin-left: auto;
}

#middle-indicator {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <div id="coopLogo">
    <div>Brand 1 logo(longer)</div>
    <div>+</div>
    <div>B2 logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="middle-indicator"></div>
```

For this to work in IE10+/Edge you need to add old syntax properties and specify columns manually (for IE/Edge also added nested flex-container). Result:

```css
#coopLogo {
  /* becoma a grid-container */
  /* its children will be grid-items */
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  /* specify column width of children */
  /* 1fr means remaining space */
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

/* just adding non-breakable space */
#coopLogo > *:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "\A0";
}

#coopLogo > :first-child {
  /* move content to the right */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#coopLogo > :nth-child(2) {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}

#coopLogo > :last-child {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}

#middle-indicator {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <div id="coopLogo">
    <div>Brand 1 logo(longer)</div>
    <div>+</div>
    <div>B2 logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="middle-indicator"></div>
```